# CSS Grid with fixed number of 100 grid cells, but flexible number of rows and colums

Tags: css, grid

I want to create a css grid with 100 grid cells. The only important thing is that there will always be 100 cells. How many columns and rows there are does not matter too much.
I am a little lost how I could achieve this with the

```
grid-template-rows: ...
grid-template-columns: ....
```

properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got you,

there are multiple ways to achieve this like `1*100=100`, `2*50=100`, `4*25=100`, `5*20=100`.

so you can you any of them and any order means first is `row/column` or and second is `row/column`.

```js
let row = [1, 2, 4, 5, 100, 50, 25, 20];
let column = [100, 50, 25, 20, 1, 2, 4, 5];

let parent = document.getElementById("parent");


parent.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${column[0]}, 1fr)`;


parent.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${row[0]}, 1fr)`;
```

```css
#parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">

</div>
```

YOu can see result by inspecting `#parent` div in dev-tools/inspect mode.

Answer (score 1):

Style for container :

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(5,auto);
grid-template-columns: repeat(20,auto);
```

Then create 100 elements (cells) as children.

**Edit**

The full answer :

`HTML CODE:`

```
<div class="parent"></div>
```

`CSS CODE:`

```
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(20, auto);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
  gap: 10px;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

`JS CODE:`

*To create 100 elements*

```
let div = document.querySelector("div");
for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  let child = document.createElement("div");
  child.className = "child";
  div.append(child);
}
```

**Note**: This edit to create 5 columns and 20 rows

Comment: but will this not always have 5 rows and 20 columns?

Comment: yes, and you can make it 20 rows and 5 columns by 
reverse the values.
And do not forget `display: grid ` for the container @RobinKohrs

Comment: Check the edit please @RobinKohrs